# Реализация паттерна Chain of Responsibility на php. Как улучшить код?

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования, чистый-код

Пытаюсь хорошо реализовать регистрацию в системе, решил использовать паттерн CoR. Дошёл до того момента, когда надо делать цепочку классов обработчиков. Результат по мне неказистый. Есть ли более изящные способы описать этот код?

```
abstract class AbstractChainHandler implements ChainHandlerInterface
{
    protected $next;

    public function setNext(ChainHandlerInterface $handler)
    {
        $this->next = $handler;
    }

    $handlers = [
        Handler1::class,
        Handler2::class,
        Handler3::class,
    ];

    public function init(array $handlers)
    {
        $result = $iterator = new $handlers[0]();

        foreach ($handlers as $handler) {
            $h = new $handler();
            $iterator->setNext();
            $iterator = $h;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/chain-of-responsibility/php/example,  https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/Behavioral/ChainOfResponsibilities/README.html  --- мне кажется тут неплохо показано.

Comment: не могу представить себе ваш useCase, можете описать, что такого у вас там происходит, что возникает ситуация под CoR?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский регистрация в несколько шагов. Сначала запоминается логин и пароль, далее забиваются инициалы, верифицируется телефон, получается адрес пользователя, его персональные данные. Всё это дело спецэфически верифицируется. До меня этот код был сделан на if else и это было просто чудовищно.  C CoR всё получилось весьма симпатично